# Mac - every command outputs 'Process completed'

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, macports

(2009 MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard — OS X 10.6.8)

I believe this is related to installing [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) today — although the other thing I did before I noticed any symptoms was install a trial of Adobe Illustrator CS6.

Initial signs were opening an extra tab in Terminal (I already had a couple open & working) — rather than give me a prompt, it just says `[Process exited - exit code 1]`.

Things I've tried:

- Trashing Terminal prefs in `~/Library/Preferences/`
- Changing 'Shell opens with' in Terminal prefs to (variously) `/usr/bin/login`, `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`
- Using Shell > New Command in Terminal to run these, and experimenting with the `--norc` and `--noprofile` switches
- Uninstalling MacPorts by following their [instructions](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling)
- Restoring the backup of my `.bash_profile` created by MacPorts, sanity checking the contents of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`
- Logging off and back on again
- Restarting the Mac
- **Logging in as another existing user and trying to start Terminal - same symptoms**
- **Attempting to run essentially anything under `/bin`** - e.g. `cat`, `chmod`, `cp`, `ls` etc - the output is usually `[Process completed]` or `[Process exited - exit code 1]`
- Running Repair Permissions in Disk Utility
- Using safe boot mode (hold down shift at startup)

There doesn't seem to be anything especially relevant in Console Log.  Note: I have Homebrew installed.

[This page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080714124323976) describes a script that'll (if it's not too old) tell me what files have been changed in Time Machine - except running that — whichever folder it's in — produces the same message.

**Answer** (see below):  Caused by file in /usr/lib/ I'd previously replaced. Fixed once restored from backup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm enough of a Unix nut that if I were you, I'd probably boot my machine off of a different drive so I could get a working shell and start spelunking around looking for the culprit.

But if you just want to get things working again, I'd recommend reinstalling Snow Leopard in-place. This essentially does a repair install. Make sure you have a good, full, tested backup first anyway, just in case.

By the way, don't just look in the Console log; also look in the "Kernel" and "System" and "All Messages" log streams in Console.app. The log named "Console" is usually just a log of output from processes run by the current user, not system-level processes and kernel events. You need to look in those other logs to see if there are clues at the system level.

Comment: Thanks for this. Fortunately was able to track it to another change I'd made - I certainly didn't want to reinstall in-place either...

Answer (score 1):

This was actually due to another recent change, where I'd seen repeated advice to replace a file in /usr/lib (`libcurl.4.dylib`) with a newer version from some website.  Fortunately I'd made a note of this and had a backup.  The error was in the Console, but only it seemed during boot, it didn't complain after that.

The moment I replaced the file everything started working again.

Comment: What did you try to do when you replaced that file?